# Can't run tomcat on port 80 on windows 7

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, windows-7, tomcat7

i want to configure tomcat 7 to use port 80 on windows 7, but seems that this port is being used by another process, and ideas how to fix that without making any problem to the system ?

here's the error i get:

```
Port 80 required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost is already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).
```

Comment: Which process does block port 80? AFAIK it is not blocked by default...

Comment: @home, i have no idea, how to know that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of experience, Skype usually blocks the port.Hope it helps.

`netstat -an |find /i "established"` could help you in this case

Comment: I'm sorry Skype usually blocks 8080, but it's worth a check

Answer (score 0):

Run netstat -ao in cmd and you will get the PID with the Port in use.

Then check in taskmgr and sort by PID to find the program blocking p80.

As a personal note: I would make a bet that you have Skype up and running, which loves to block port 80